# Удалить ссылку из js и добавить блок

Tags: javascript

Можно ли из этого скрипта удалить ссылку www.blogger.com и добавить вместо этого свой блок? Например `<div id='menu'>...</div>`

```
function share42(f,u,t,m1,m2){if(!u)u=location.href;if(!t)t=document.title;u=encodeURIComponent(u);t=encodeURIComponent(t);if(!m1)m1=150;if(!m2)m2=20;document.write('<span id="share42">');var s=new Array('"#" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.blogger.com/blog_this.pyra?t&u='+u+'&n='+t+'\', \'_blank\', \'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=200, top=200, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0\');return false" title="Опубликовать в Blogger.com"');for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)document.write('<a rel="nofollow" style="display:block;width:32px;height:32px;margin:0 0 6px;outline:none;background:url('+f+'icons.png) -'+32*i+'px 0" href='+s[i]+' target="_blank"></a>');document.write('</span>'); window.onload=function(){var p=document.getElementById('share42');function m(){var top=Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);if(top+m2<m1){p.style.top=m1-top+'px';}else{p.style.top=m2+'px';}}m();window.onscroll=m;}}
```

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Comment: Ну мне нужно просто удалить полностью внутренности, а добавить туда свой код, который бы заключался в один див. А сам я во всем этом не разбираюсь.

Comment: Имхо проще опишите что вы хотите добиться от этого, может кто напишит новый скрипт. Потому как если убирать ссылку а вернее window.open, то это заново переписывать функцию, лишний гемор)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл действия не ясен, но если не особо задумываться, то:

```
function share42 (f,u,t,m1,m2) {
    // Unused params: f,u,t

    if (!u) {
        u = location.href;
    }
    u = encodeURIComponent(u);

    if (!t) {
        t = document.title;
    }
    t = encodeURIComponent(t);

    if (!m1) {
        m1 = 150;
    }
    if (!m2) {
        m2 = 20;
    }

    document.write('<div id="menu">');
    document.write('</span>');
    window.onload = function() {
        var p = document.getElementById('menu');

        function m() {
            var top = Math.max(
                document.body.scrollTop,
                document.documentElement.scrollTop
            );

            p.style.top = ((top + m2 < m1) ? m1 - top : m2) + 'px'   
        }
        m();
        window.onscroll = m;
    }
}
```

Пробелы и переводы строки можно убрать по-вкусу. Пере-форматированный блок кода можно [посмотреть здесь](https://gist.github.com/1483843).

Но в общем и целом для создания подобного меню достаточно только CSS, [узнать больше про `position:fixed`](http://alt-f4.ru/css-position-fixed)